# Checking if a program is running on local network

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, localhost

I want to write a simple program in c++ that use tcp socket to communicate with the same program on another computer in lan.
To create the tcp socket I could make the user write the ip and the port to make the connection. But I also need to be able to autodetect in the local area network if there is any computer also running the program.

My idea was:

- when the program is autodetecting for available connection in lan, it will send all ips a message via udp to a specific port, meanwhile it will also keep listening to a port waiting to eventual answer.
- when the program on the other computer is opened for lan connection, it will keep listening to the a port in case another computer is trying to detect, then it will send also via udp the response messagee notifying the possibility of connection.

All the security system is another problem for which I don't need answer now.

```
// Client 1:
// Search for all ips in local network
// create udp socket
// send check message
// thread function listening for answers
// if device found than show to menu
// continue searching process


// Client 2 (host) :
// user enable lan connection
// create udp socket
// thread function listening for detection requests
// if request structure is right send back identification message
// continue listening for request
```

My question - Is there a more efficient or standard way to do something like that?

Comment: What does "sending socket request to all ips in the network" mean? Networks vary in size, considerably, and sending requests to "all IPs" is not necessarily practical, nor a good idea.

Comment: Are you really asking about something like [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) with auto-discovery tools like [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software))?

Comment: depends on how big the network is. If you have small network(a few dozens) you could use Broadcast. If the network is large, I don't think is feasible.

Comment: @Heto Can your broadcast to connect with a TCP socket?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: I'm sorry if my message created confusion. You cannot broadcast directly via TCP. You must use UDP for broadcast. After you have the broadcaster IP, the receiver can connect to the broadcaster via TCP(with a new connection). Hope this clarifies my thought process.

Answer (score 0):

Testing whether another computer is listening on a given port is what hackers do all day to try to take over the world...

When writing a software like you describe, though, you want to specify the IP and port information. A reason to search and automatically find a device would be if you are implementing a printer, for example. In that case, as suggested by Hero, you could use broadcasting. However, in that case, you use UDP (because TCP does not support that feature).

The software on one side must have a server, which in TCP parlance means a `listen()` call followed by an `accept()` until a connection materialized.

The client on the other side can then attempt a `connect()`. If the connect works, then the software on the other side is up and running.

If you need both to be able to attempt a connection, then both must implement the client and server (which is doable if you use `ppoll()` [or the old `select()`] you know which event is happening and can act on it, no need for threads or `fork()`).

On my end, I wrote the [eventdispatcher library](https://github.com/m2osw/eventdispatcher) to do all those things under the hood. I also want many computers to communicate between each others, so I have a form of RPC service I call [communicatord](https://github.com/m2osw/communicatord). This service is at the same time a client and a server. It listens on a port and tries to connect to other systems. If the other system has a lower IP address, it is considered a server. Otherwise, it is viewed as a client and I disconnect after sending a `GOSSIP` message. That way the client (larger IP address) can in turn connect to the server. This *communicator* service allows all my other services to communicate without having to re-implement the communication layer between computer over and over again.